# I watched a TV talk show headlined “The tank hits hot topics”，and what does the word "tank" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, pun

I've just watched a TV talk show with a headline of “The tank hits hot topics”,and  I guess it might be a shorter form of "think tank"? If it was, is such a shorter form of "think tank" acceptable and common in English? I have a suspicion that in this headline, the word "tank" is purposely used to convey a double meaning.

I am not sure if that usage is a pun.

[image]

Comment: What is the talk show about?  The topic can help define the title for the topic.

Comment: It wouldn't happen to be a special episode of [Shark Tank](http://abc.go.com/shows/shark-tank/about-the-show), would it?

Comment: It talks about some hot news and the guests speak out their views about the hot topics.

Comment: @ J.R.♦  I’ve just posted a screen shot in the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no pun here<sup>1</sup>, just typical headline-ese: "the Tank" here is shorthand for "some of the stars of the show *Shark Tank*", "hit" is headline-speak for "talk about", and "hot topics" means more or less what it sounds like.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Whether or not it's a pun to name a show that's not about wildlife *Shark Tank* is a different question.</sub>

Comment: WOW, how illuminating! I know little about "Shark Tank".